# How to change a Persistent Volume to use a path on the Host machine?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have created, entirely through the Web console, a Persistent Volume Claim and attached to the /www/log mount path of my Web Server. 
I see the Persistent Volume Claim works as if I restart the Pod, the logs are preserved.

I'd like, however, to use a **local mount** on the Host for the Persistent Volume so that I can tail my logs easily.
On the OKD Web console you can only create new PVC but you cannot create a PV pointing to a local mount.
Can you advice how to update the Persistent Volume picked up automatically to use a local mount (e.g. /mnt/data) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be resolved by using **hostPath** option **Persistent Volume YAML** in OpenShift running through the command line. But, there are some things to watch out if you want to go down this path.

1. All the files and directories created in the path `/mnt/data` are only writable by **root** user. In this case either you have to run a **privileged container** or give appropriate **permission** to the hostPath to be writable.
2. The below **YAML** has the syntax of **hostPath** option in Persistent volume.

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolume
   metadata:
     name: test-pv
   spec:
     capacity:
       storage: 1Mi
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
     hostPath:
       path: /mnt/data
   ```
3. Run the following command to create the persistent volume in the specific project. `oc create -f test-pv.yaml -n <project>`
4. Once you have the Persistent volume available, create a **Persistent volume claim** that **bounds** to the above created Persistent volume.
5. If you want to mount the hostPath directly on a Pod, please make sure that you use a **node selector** in the deployment config as the pods are **ephemeral** and they can be recreated at any point in time. If the pods with the hostPath is scheduled on another host that might not have the `/mnt/data` path available, it could result a`CrashLoopBackOff` error.
6. The below **YAML** is an example for the **hostPath** on a **Pod**.

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: test-pod
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: tomcat
       name: test-container
       volumeMounts:
       - mountPath: /www/log
         name: test-volume
     volumes:
     - name: test-volume
       hostPath:
         # directory location on host
         path: /mnt/data
         # this field is optional
         type: Directory
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!